# Can we use parentheses instead of equal sign while assigning a value to paramethers in function?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

So, I was just watching a tutorial from WebDevSimplified, and here is that piece of code that bothers me.

```
const failure1 = false;
const failure2 = false;

function callbackFunction(callback, errorCallback) {
    if (failure1) {
        errorCallback({
            name: 'Negative event1 occurred',
            message: ':('
        })
    } else if (failure2) {
        errorCallback({
            name: 'Negative event2 occurred',
            message: ':/'
        })
    } else {
        callback('Mission complete!')
    }
}

callbackFunction((message) => {
    console.log('Success: ' + message)
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error.name + ' ' + error.message)
})
```

So, why exactly is there a value assigned to the function parameters like this:

```
callback('Mission complete!')
```

Because according to every information I found on the internet I would do it like this:

```
callback = 'Mission complete'
```

Yet, when I do it this way, it's not working. I really feel super bad right now, because this seems very trivial and I cannot find any information about it. I would really appreciate it if someone would explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The syntaxes have completely different meanings.

---

This assigns a value to `callback`:

```
callback = 'Mission complete'
```

---

This calls the function `callback` and passes an argument to it:

```
callback('Mission complete!')
```

The value will be assigned to the variable specified in the first argument of the function definition:

```
function callback(this_is_the_variable) {
     if (this_is_the_variable === 'Mission complete!') {
         // something
     }
}
```

(In your example `this_is_the_variable` is named `message`)

Comment: Still, that line code looks weird:
                                                                                                                                                           
errorCallback({
            name: 'Negative event1 occurred',
            message: ':('
        })                                                

Can I pass an object as a parameter of a function like this?

Comment: You can pass any kind of value.